# How do I remove a PC from the synced list

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center, sync, oneconf

Is there a way to erase one pc from the list (of the synced computers) created on the left side of the Software Center?

I mean, the pc is not listed in the Ubuntu One panel (not synced) anymore, but I have it in the Software Center and all the applications of the various computers (new ones and old ones, synced and not synced anymore) are still there.

Any way?

Comment: Im trying to deal with the same issue, i had a problem with my video drivers, and since i had just installed ubuntu, i opted to install it again. Now i have more "sync" computers, than computers i actually own. So.. trying to figure out how to "un-sync" some of them..

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

Log into your ubuntu account at https://login.ubuntu.com/. There's a tab called "Applications" showing when you have given access to which applications from which computer. Just remove the relevant entry *Ubuntu Software Center @ yourhostname*.

Answer (score 1):

```
oneconf-query --list --hosts
```

This will give you a list of all the registered hosts including the duplicates which have different hostids even though they all have the same hostnames. Make note of the ones you want to delete and then ......

```
oneconf-query --hide-inventory --hostid=bigfrigginglong32digitmachineid!
```

You will find the entry associated with this machine id is no longer in the list generated by the first command and when software-center is restarted, it will disappear from there as well. I guess this can only be done from the command line for now.